# ¿Cómo establecer una fecha fija en un p:calendar?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, calendar

Tengo el siguiente p:calendar

```
<p:calendar id="popup1"  placeholder="Fecha Fin" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"  locale="es" 
                            rendered="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.fechaValida(NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona.fecFinNivel) }" value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona.fecFinNivel}" >

                </p:calendar>
```

el cual en el atributo render, mando a llamar el siguiente metodo

```
  public boolean fechaValida(Date date) {

    String strFecha = "31/12/3000";

    String fechaFormateada;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    fechaFormateada = sdf1.format(date);

    return !fechaFormateada.equals(strFecha);
}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando haya registros con fecha `31/12/3000`, no se muestre nada en el p:calendar, y lo hace, pero me desaparece toda la cajita del p:calendar

¿Cómo le puedo hacer para que solamente no muestre la fecha?

Comment: Lo que se puede hacer es un rango pero no se si así te funcionara?

Comment: un rango de fecha a tal fecha? o como?

Comment: algo como esto mindate="4/1/14"

Comment: pero el mindate solo sirve para no escoger fechas  atras de una cierta fecha, no?

Comment: No es para marcar un minimo y desde ahi en adelante se puedan escoger las fechas

Comment: para que el `p:calendar` no te muestre la fecha seleccionada, tendrias que establecer su value en `null`

Comment: @Root93 te funciona de esta manera?

Comment: @RaulCacacho, cual manera, la del min?

Comment: @Root93 <p:calendar id="popup1"  placeholder="Fecha Fin" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"  locale="es" 
                            rendered="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.fechaValida(NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona.fecFinNivel) }" value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona.fecFinNivel}"    maxdate="31/12/2550"> 

                </p:calendar>

Comment: @Root93 te investigue y hay maxdate te deje el ejemplo con el año 2550

Comment: @RaulCacacho, ya lo probe, pero el problema es que cuando es esa fecha, no me renderiza la cajita del calendar, y yo quiero que si salga, pero sin esa fecha, o sea en balnco

Comment: @Klaimmore, ya lo intente, pero cuando le seto null, tambien lo cambia en la bd, todos los que estan en esa fecha los cambia a null y asi no debo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75434/discussion-between-root93-and-raul-cacacho).

Answer (score 1):

Puedes lograrlo haciendo uso de un `converter`.

Este es el código en la vista:

```
<p:calendar value="#{control.fecha}" showOn="button" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"  locale="es" converter="convertidorFecha">
    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" update="@this" delay="500" process="@this" />
</p:calendar>
```

Y este es el código del `converter`:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;

/**
 * Convertidor para fechas
 *
 */
@FacesConverter("convertidorFecha")
public class ConverterFecha implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (value != null && value.trim().length() > 0) {
            try {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                Date date = new Date(sdf.parse(value).getTime());
                return date;
            } catch (ParseException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ConverterFecha.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value != null && value instanceof Date) {
            Calendar fechaCompara = Calendar.getInstance();
            fechaCompara.setTime((Date) value);

            if (fechaCompara.get(Calendar.DATE) == 31 && fechaCompara.get(Calendar.MONTH) == 11 && fechaCompara.get(Calendar.YEAR) == 3000) {
                return null;
            }
            Date fecha = (Date) value;
            return new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(fecha);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Le he puesto un `p:ajax` para hacer pruebas seleccionando diferentes fechas y comprobar que funcionaba.